# Flutter Firebase delete function with httpsCallable

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm creating Flutter app using Firebase as backend.
My app is SNS app like Insta, Facebook.

User can create their own card and other user can reply on there.
I finished works for creating & deleting card using Firebase.

In case of creating function, they are in user-side(App), and in case of deleting function, I put them into Firebase functions.

My question is about Deleting functions is Firebase.
I used "FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable" to call the function in Firebase.
The function which "FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable" calls from Firebase works like below flow.

**----------start**

1. **read Card data**
2. **find** writer of this card > **update** user information to remove data which this user created.
3. **find** users who press likes on this card > **update** user information to remove data which this user liked.
4. **find** users who replied on this card > **update** user information to remove data which this user liked.
5. if there is re-reply card on the reply card, repeat this process for that reply card

**----------end**

But the problem is **it takes quite long time**.
After user press the delete button, it take 1~3min to delete whole data.
And if it takes this much longer, other user can reply on this card again before fully it is fully deleted and then I don't know what gonna be happend...

I think if I put this delete function into user-side(App), it would not be takes long as much as this.

Please give me your opinion about **why this flow takes so long time** and give me a good **counter proposer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain why the deletion takes so much time without seeing the code for it.

---

In general, you'll want to mark the card as "deleted" as step 0, so before even starting the other work, by writing a special value to it. In all your other actions, always check if a card is marked as deleted before taking any operation on it.

The card is from that point on referred to as a [tombstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(data_store)), as it indicates an object that no longer is supposed to exist for the app.

---

Finally, consider performing the operations on the top-level card(s) in a transaction, so that they are automatically rejected and retried when a user likes the card while you're updating it.

You can also repeatedly perform the delete operation (on non-tombstoned cards), until there are no more cards to process.

Comment: Thank you sir... I got goose bumps. "by writing a special value to it" this can be the solution on my project.... And I am surprised that you propose me a correct solution even without seeing my code at all.... Really appreciate for you advice..!!!!!

Comment: Sir, I have one more question. I have never thought about using tombstone concept. But is it normal concept to develope SNS App?? If it is, is there somewhere to learn some basic concept to design this kinda way??

Comment: Tombstones are a database concept, so not specific to any sort of app. I linked the wikipedia page in my answer, but there's probably other explanations as well. I'd recommend searching for it, and checking the top results.